# Android UIobject - container's Child element is taken from next container if child not exists

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

So I am having an Instagram tool using the uiautomator2 lib.
https://github.com/openatx/uiautomator2

Instead of getting Empty / not found issue, **I am getting the sibling value.**

I am reading the all "containers" and getting full name using a child(follow_list_container):
[image]

this is the way i do it:

```
containers = self.device(resourceId='com.instagram.android:id/follow_list_container')
```

Now when I reach the "sh__roseeeasd" container (which dont have full name)
[image]

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    user_info_view = container.child(index=1)
    user_info_view.child(resourceId="com.instagram.android:id/follow_list_subtitle")
```

the fullname_view.get_text() is the **SIBLING**:

[image]
dump XML Hierarchy:
[image]

**instead of return EMPTY / NOT FOUND.**

Why is that ? the child should be only from parent !